# Transient Suppressing Portion Of Relay - Ohm Test

Tags: relay

I have two different relays.

I am OHMING the Transient Suppression (diode & zener) portion and the results are weird.

M83536/16-021L reads FB of 300 ohms and RB of infinity.
M83536/26-001L reads FB of 240 ohms and RB of 220 ohms.

Both relays energize properly and the contacts switch.

The image of the diode and zener for both relays are stamped identical on the cases (see attached).

Does anyone know why the ohm results are different? Yes, I looked for datasheets, no help.

Much thanks.

[image]

Here are the two datasheets:

[image: M83536-26-001L]
[image: M83536-16-02L]

Comment: Please DON'T use all CAPITALS in the title of your question, it looks like you're shouting. *I am OHMING* No you're not, you're **measuring the resistance**. Have you considered that you're just measuring the **coil** of the relay?

Comment: Ohming is how we say measuring resistance. May not be the proper words but did not realize I needed to watch my etiquette when reaching out for info. Yes, I did consider the coil ohms but then both types of relays should have read similiar value (FB - coil, RB - inifinity). That is why I reached out. Could not understand why they measured differently.

Comment: Do you also say "Volting" when measuring a voltage?

Comment: LOL. I was just thinking of that. No, we don't. But for whatever reason, we say ohm whenever we mean resistance measurement.

Comment: I think I'll go and do some AMPING and a spot of FARADING.

Comment: I added the datasheets (above)

Answer (score 1):

The M83536 numbers refer to a standard.

K-D2N-300L meets M83536/16-021L and has a resistance of 290 Ohms, so your measurement of 300 Ohms is expected. The nominal operating voltage is 24v.

A relay meeting M83536/26-001L has a resistance of 210 Ohms, so your measurement of 220 Ohms is expected. The nominal operating voltage is also 24v.

The difference in resistance is purely down to the design of the relay and how much mechanical force the coil should apply to the contacts.

The purpose of the Zenier diode is to provide a path for the high voltage back EMF from the coil. The second datasheet indicates that the diode will conduct if the reverse voltage is above 42 Volts. When you measure the resistance with a Ohmmeter you are not using a high enough voltage to pass a current through the Zenier diode, so it does not conduct. You only see the resistance of the coil.

Comment: Yes, the coil ohms is on target for both type of relays. My question is why does the transient suppression (diode and zener) ohm as if they are FB (coil ohm value) when I check RB.  I even order a new one from supply. Same result. Just curious if anyone knows why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there are a bunch of different internal schematics, as shown on this [datasheet](https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=showdoc&DocId=Catalog+Section%7F5-1773450-5_sec1_07%7F0313%7Fpdf%7FEnglish%7FENG_CS_5-1773450-5_sec1_07_0313_5-1773450-5_Sec1_07.pdf%7F4-1617004-8).

[image]

You didn't link the relevant datasheet and I certainly don't have the patience to try to figure out the military numbering system of these old and very expensive relays, but that's probably what's going on- the series/parallel diode in (2), likely.

Drop-out will be significantly slower with the series/parallel diode compared to the zener/diode.

Comment: @user243776 Please do not edit someone else's answer to insert new information or pose questions. Rather post a comment below the relevant answer, or update your own question.